# Why doesn't ImageView load my image?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development so forgive my lack of knowledge on this. 
I'm trying to make an app that finds an image stored in internal memory and displays it in an ImageView. I've gone through multiple ways to do this but the image is never displayed.

Here's my code so far:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.FrontImage);
    bv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.BackImage);
    Bitmap myBitmap;
    File imgFile = new  File(PATH,"front1.png");
    //check if image exists
    if(imgFile.exists())
    {
              //get image
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap); //add image to ImageView
            tv.setText(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }            
}
```

I think the TextView tv displays the correct path but the image doesn't load. 
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: *The TextView tv displays the correct path* ... this should be: *The TextView tv displays, **i think**, the correct path* ... then you should use logcat to check what `imgFile.exists()` returns

Comment: What is the value of `PATH`?

Comment: PATH is Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();.
@Selvin imgFile.exists() returned true.

Comment: Okay it turns out I was missing access permissions. Sorry to bother you. I guess this is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add read permission in manifest, other wise myBitmap will be always null.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```